# Django __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

Im using Django 2.0.1

Basically I'm trying to implement [cropperjs](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs) and first I was havving trouble with an 403, that prevented me from uploading an image (this is because the script returns a Json response and I didn't have my view to handle it) and so I did, but then I ran into this problem. Please help I don't deserve this, I pay my taxes.

On my forms.py

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Employee
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['user', 'date_joined','Credits_earned','skills']

  department = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
        "placeholder": _("User...")
    }
    )
  )
  title = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        "class": "form-control",
        "placeholder": _("Title...")
    }
    )
  )
  avatar = forms.ImageField(
    widget=forms.FileInput()
  )
```

on my views.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse


class EmployeeUpdate(JsonResponse,UpdateView):
    template_name = 'test.html'
    model = Employee
    form_class = EmployeeForm
    success_url = '/'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(EmployeeUpdate, self).get_queryset().filter(user=self.kwargs['pk'])

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        return self.render_to_json_response(context, **response_kwargs)
```

The script on the template:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var avatar = document.getElementById('avatar'); // Current avatar
var image = document.getElementById('image');
var input = document.getElementById('id_avatar'); // Image input
var $progress = $('.progress');
var $progressBar = $('.progress-bar');
var $alert = $('.alert');
var $modal = $('#modal');
var cropper;

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  var files = e.target.files;
  var done = function (url) {
    input.value = '';
    image.src = url;
    $alert.hide();
    $modal.modal('show');
  };
  var reader;
  var file;
  var url;

  if (files && files.length > 0) {
    file = files[0];

    if (URL) {
      done(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    } else if (FileReader) {
      reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        done(reader.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
});

$modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  cropper = new Cropper(image, {
    aspectRatio: 1,
    viewMode: 3,
  });
}).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  cropper.destroy();
  cropper = null;
});

document.getElementById('crop').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var initialAvatarURL;
  var canvas;

  $modal.modal('hide');

  if (cropper) {
    canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
      width: 160,
      height: 160,
    });

    initialAvatarURL = avatar.src;
    avatar.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    $progress.show();
    $alert.removeClass('alert-success alert-warning');
    canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
      var formData = new FormData();

      formData.append('avatar', blob);

      $.ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,

        xhr: function () {
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

          xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
            var percent = '0';
            var percentage = '0%';

            if (e.lengthComputable) {
              percent = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
              percentage = percent + '%';
              $progressBar.width(percentage).attr('aria-valuenow', percent).text(percentage);
            }
          };

          return xhr;
        },

        success: function () {
          $alert.show().addClass('alert-success').text('Upload success');
        },

        error: function () {
          avatar.src = initialAvatarURL;
          $alert.show().addClass('alert-warning').text('Upload error');
        },

        complete: function () {
          $progress.hide();
        },
      });
    });
  }
});
});
</script>
```

**Edit:**
Here's the full Traceback:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/test2/1

Django Version: 2.0.1
Python Version: 3.6.1
Installed Applications:
['accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
'dashboard.apps.DashboardConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles']

Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Loki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\Loki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "C:\Users\Loki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Loki\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 63, in view
self = cls(**initkwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

Comment: it's probably that you forgot to add an extra value on the `def get_queryset`, else you'd have to look which file and line the error is coming from

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: [...]\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py this is the file that throws the error (I dont have any field, module or anything called data), im assuming is som *arg that needs to be passed to the UpdateView, although i'm not sure how, I tried to add it to `get_queryset` just in case. But didn't work

Comment: Can you post the entire error + base.py @Loki ?

Comment: I fixed it, the first error was that I typed `class Employee(JsonResponse[...])` not `class Employee(JSONResponseMixin[...])` also my `JSONResponseMixin` wasn't properly configured. Now I ran into a `Object of type 'Employee' is not JSON serializable` error

Answer (score 0):

Well, what ended up working was this snipped:

```
# encoding: utf-8
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

MIMEANY = '*/*'
MIMEJSON = 'application/json'
MIMETEXT = 'text/plain'


def response_mimetype(request):
     """response_mimetype -- Return a proper response mimetype, accordingly to
    what the client accepts, as available in the `HTTP_ACCEPT` header.

    request -- a HttpRequest instance.

"""
    can_json = MIMEJSON in request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT']
    can_json |= MIMEANY in request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT']
    return MIMEJSON if can_json else MIMETEXT


    class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    """JSONResponse -- Extends HTTPResponse to handle JSON format response.

   This response can be used in any view that should return a json stream of
   data.

    Usage:

        def a_iew(request):
            content = {'key': 'value'}
            return JSONResponse(content, mimetype=response_mimetype(request))

"""
    def __init__(self, obj='', json_opts=None, mimetype=MIMEJSON, *args, **kwargs):
        json_opts = json_opts if isinstance(json_opts, dict) else {}
        content = json.dumps(obj, **json_opts)
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, mimetype, *args, **kwargs)
```

And then in my view:

```
class EmployeeUpdate(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'test.html'
    model = Employee
    form_class = EmployeeForm
    success_url = '/'



    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(EmployeeUpdate, self).get_queryset().filter(user=self.kwargs['pk'])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        data = {'data': 'formData'}
        response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype=response_mimetype(self.request))
        return response
```

I still need to fix something in my template so the input goes where it should. Although thanks for the hep though.